# Migration from legacy HashMap to Mapping

Tags: ink, mapping

I have following code where I want to use with new `Mapping` (now it works but with legacy `HashMap`). I think that the source code below is self-explanatory:

```rs
    self.balances 
        .entry(caller)
        .and_modify(|val| *val += new_balance)
        .or_insert(new_balance);
```

My doubt is how to rewrite the source code to use `Mapping`, like below:

```rs
    balances: Mapping<AccountId, Balance>
```

I think that developers will want to use `Mapping` often to update entries and I have issues to `rewrite` the source code.

Comment: this example might help you [here](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/master/integration-tests/mapping-integration-tests/lib.rs) to use mapping in contract

Comment: before asking the question I was looking at examples of Mapping, but was not able to find example with modifying/inserting - in the example that you have linked I am also not able to find more of less similar to my code/question per se, thanks anyhow ;-)